java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector Not being loaded when running for a jar
I have several customer java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector classes, to discover custom file formats but it appears that the spring boot application when running via the Jar is not loading these classes.
This all works from the IDE, I have the java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector file within the resources/META-INF/services directory.
I have tired modify the gradle file to include them, but received different error related to the BOOT-INF directory and how the spring boot application is built. I have also tried added -cp 'BOOT-INF/lib/*:BOOT-INF/classes:.' to the start command as well.
Update: 10/15/24
Code has been pushed to a git repo https://github.com/artroup/Spring-SPI-Error for anyone trying to help. Sample files are in the TestFiles dir at the root. To leverage the files the path in the controller class will need to be modified. Then to run it’s just http://localhost:8111/status

What are the errors you are getting? Show the code, show the exception (full stacktrace).

There are no errors being received. I am just following the standard implementation of the FileTypeDetector SPI for java. I have my classes the extend the FileTypeDetector class and then include the java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector file in a META-INF/Services directory under the resources folder.

Then how do you know those classes aren't loaded? Please show the code, configuration etc. don't describe. Ideally you have a re-producer so we can see what is wrong. Also how are you running the application when packaged?

Please look at https://github.com/artroup/Spring-SPI-Error. If you pull the code you will just need to change the directory path in the FileTypeController class. This will need to be build and ran via the jar file. THIS WILL WORK RUNNING FROM AN IDE.

Please don't shout (that is if you write in all uppercase) as that is considered rude.

Are the files you are testing part of the jar, or are they submitted? That being said if you have additional information please edit your question, instead of adding that in just comments.

The file examples are in the repo in the TestFile dir, which in the FileTypeController will need be changed before someone complies for their system. If you’d like me to make a change let me know.
Then you will just need to hit http://localhosr:8111/status and it should say pcap and not null

You are running into classloader issues when packaged as a jar. Not sure who is at fault here. When packaged Spring Boot uses a dedicated classloader, however the File Type SPI forces the System Classloader. Due to this the latter cannot see the classes or files. So even moving them or adding parameters won't help I'm afraid. I would report a bug with Spring Boot to see if they can do something to resolve this.

Would you mind sharing with me the command you ran to verify that? When I run the following: 'java -jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` . I still receive null

I added some code to manually invoke the ServiceLoader. One with the classloader from Spring Boot, which is the System classloader when running in the IDE the other forced to the system classloader. When packaged they are different the Spring one can load them the system one cannot. Hence a classloading issue.
